# Solve for $x$ given $\sin x$ and $2\cos(2x)$

Tags: functions, trigonometry, derivatives

I am trying to find absolute maximum and absolute minimum values for$\ f(x)=\cos(x)+\sin(2x)$ on the interval $\ [0,\fracπ2]$.

I started off by finding the derivative:

$\ f'(x)=-\sin x+2\cos(2x)$

Then I tried to find the critical numbers.  But that's where I ran amuck.  I came up with:

$\sin x=2\cos(2x)$

How do I go about solving for x?

Comment: Use $\cos 2x=1-2\sin^2x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use that $$\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2 (x)$$ plugging this in your equation we get
$$-\sin(x)+2(1-2\sin^2 (x))=0$$ this is a quadratic equation in $\sin(x)$

Comment: Sorry, not sure I've understood how that helps.

Comment: does it help now?

Comment: Ahh... I think I'm catching the idea now...

Comment: then good solving now

Comment: Thanks for the help, got it!